# Initializing ZeroMQ 2.2 message in "almost always auto" style wants to use private constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, zeromq

I have written a C++11 program which uses ZeroMQ.

In one particular line I want to create a new message as a local variable and initialize it with the size of a vector called `serialized`, using the ["almost always auto"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)-style syntax:

```
auto zm = zmq::message_t {serialized.size()};
```

This compiles fine on my machine (let's call it machine "A"; using Clang++ version 3.4.2-13 and also using g++ version 4.9.1), while on a colleague's machine ("B"; using Clang++ version 3.5.0-10) an error occurs:

```
error: calling a private constructor of class 'zmq::message_t'
    auto zm = zmq::message_t {serialized.size()};
              ^
/usr/include/zmq.hpp:192:9: note: declared private here
        message_t (const message_t&);
        ^
```

Both machines are running Debian 8.0 (jessie). Machine A has [libzmq3-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libzmq3-dev) installed (ZeroMQ version 4.0.5+dfsg-2), while on machine B [libzmq-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libzmq-dev) (ZeroMQ version  2.2.0+dfsg-6) is installed. When comparing the two versions of `zmq.hpp` contained in the respective packages, the following sections are probably relevant for this issue.

On machine A:

```
class message_t
{
    // ...

public:
    inline explicit message_t (size_t size_)
    {
        int rc = zmq_msg_init_size (&msg, size_);
        if (rc != 0)
            throw error_t ();
    }

    // ...

#ifdef ZMQ_HAS_RVALUE_REFS
    inline message_t (message_t &&rhs) : msg (rhs.msg)
    {   
        int rc = zmq_msg_init (&rhs.msg);
        if (rc != 0)
            throw error_t (); 
    }   

    inline message_t &operator = (message_t &&rhs)
    {   
        std::swap (msg, rhs.msg);
        return *this;
    }   
#endif

    // ...

private:
    zmq_msg_t msg;
    message_t (const message_t&);
    void operator = (const message_t&);
};
```

On machine B:

```
class message_t : private zmq_msg_t
{
    // ...

public:
    inline message_t (size_t size_)
    {
        int rc = zmq_msg_init_size (this, size_);
        if (rc != 0)
            throw error_t ();
    }

    // no move constructor/move assignment

    // ...

private:
    message_t (const message_t&);
    void operator = (const message_t&);
};
```

When I change my code to this

```
zmq::message_t zmq {serialized.size()};
```

the error on machine B goes away.

My questions are:

1. I intend to invoke the `message_t (size_t)` constructor. Why is there an attempt to use `message_t (const message_t&)`, which is private, on machine B?
2. The change in the code that makes the error go away removes the assignment operator. Why did the compiler then not complain about `void operator = (const message_t&)` being private, but `message_t (const message_t&)`?
3. Why is there no error on machine A, although `message_t (const message_t&)` is also private there? I guess it has something to do with `message_t (size_t)` being declared `explicit`, but I do not understand the effects of this keyword. *(edit: I originally wasn't aware that there is a move constructor in machine A's version, which does not exist in machine B's version.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following

```
auto zm = zmq::message_t {serialized.size()};
```

is not an assignation,
but initialize `zm` with move or copy constructor (which may be elided) which should be accessible (even if it is elided).

The temporary is construct with `explicit message_t (size_t)` as expected.

<strike>I suspect a bug in Clang++ version 3.4.2-13 as you should have the same error as in machine B.</strike> (Move operator in A that B doesn't have explain this behavior).

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in Clang, as it also compiles using g++ version 4.9.1. (I have updated the question to mention this).

Comment: @mkrieger1: See [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8613c5cef04cb13f). Both (recent) clang/g++ reject the code (correctly). So if example code works for you, there is a bug. (or else you hide relevant code as move constructor).

Comment: That is a good point. There is indeed a move constructor and a move assignment in machine A's version of ZeroMQ that is not there on machine B's version. I've updated the question.

Comment: So does `explicit` or not actually play a role here?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Do you still have some point which is not clear now ?

Comment: `explicit` doesn't play a role here. `explicit` disallows to call `void foo(message_t)` with `foo(42)`, you have to call it with `foo(message_t{42})` instead.

Comment: Yes: why is the copy/move *constructor* `message_t(const message_t&)`/`message_t(message_t&&)` used, and not the copy/move *assignment* `operator=`?

Comment: You may look at [copy_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Answer (score 1):

```
auto zm = zmq::message_t {serialized.size()};
```

is a variable declaration so in this case **=** is a copy-initialisation not an affectation that`s why this is the constructor that is called and not the affectation operator.
Explicit keyword mean that the constructor is only considered for direct initialisation which is the case with

```
zmq::message_t zmq {serialized.size()};
```

You can find more details and examples here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: But why does the first syntax not result in an error on machine A?

Answer (score -1):

Turn

```
auto zm = zmq::message_t {serialized.size()};
```

into

```
izmq::message_t zm {serialized.size()};
```

as the = calls the (undesired, private) copy constructor

Comment: Yes, I know this already. My questions are about *why* this is so, and *why* it is not an error on one of the machines.